# How would we manually find the ASN of a network?

Tags: bgp

When it comes to ASN and lookups I always wondered how these sites obtain these lists. I see it's not always real-time as numbers change and assume it's scanned. Is there any links, write-ups or information on this?

Comment: I would like to know mostly how I am to find an ASN on my own without APIs but becoming the API. I can't imagine sending requests to infamous sites if I could handle the load myself and prevent restrictions/etc.

Comment: https://securitytrails.com/blog/asn-lookup lists some common tools